# Custom button action in push notification

Tags: ios, swift

i add two buttons in push notification and am able to perform such action while app is in foreground or background mode.i am happy with that but i cant perform action when app is killed.

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    print(userInfo)
    guard let apsdata = userInfo[AnyHashable("data")] as? [String:AnyObject]  else {
            return
    }

    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "ACCEPT_ACTION":
         if let pushdatadict = apsdata["body"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AcceptOfNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: pushdatadict)
         }
        print("request accepted buddy")
    case "DECLINE_ACTION":
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "RejectOfNotification"), object: nil)
        print("request decline buddy")
    default:
        break
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {

```
            switch response.actionIdentifier {
            case "ACCEPT_ACTION":
                APIToAcceptTheUserRequest()
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let url = URL(string: "open://Home") {
                        self.extensionContext?.open(url) { success in
                            print(success)
                        }
                    }
                })
                print("request accepted buddy")

            case "DECLINE_ACTION":
                APIToRejectTheUserRequest()

            default:
                break
            }
completion(UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption.dismissAndForwardAction)
```

}